# Set a Countdown timer on Alert Controller Title text

Tags: swift, nstimer, uialertcontroller

I have an Alert controller which will takes minute input and show the countdown to the title of the controller and also highlighted the selected action.

[image]

How can I update the timer on the title, and make bold the selected Action.
My Alert controller code is:-

```
 let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Set Timer", message: "--:--", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    
    let time10 = UIAlertAction(title: "10 Minutes", style: .default) {
        
        action in
        self.totalTime = 600
        self.startTimer()
        
    }
    
    let time20 = UIAlertAction(title: "20 Minutes", style: .default) {
        
        action in
        self.totalTime = 1200
        self.startTimer()
    }
    
    let timeCustom = UIAlertAction(title: "Custom", style: .default) {
        
        action in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "customTimer", sender: nil)
        
    }
    
    
    actionSheet.addAction(time10)
    actionSheet.addAction(time20)
    actionSheet.addAction(timeCustom)
    actionSheet.addAction(cancel)
    
    present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}

// startTimer()

func startTimer() {
        
        countdownTimer?.invalidate()

            countdownTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
    @objc func updateTime() {
        
        print("update:- \(totalTime)")
        
        if totalTime != 0 {
            totalTime -= 1
        } else {
            
            endTimer()
        }
    }
    
    func endTimer() {
        print("end:- \(totalTime)")
    
        countdownTimer?.invalidate()
        
        print("timer end")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the action as instance property and as an alert ,update the message with the remaining time and also define the preferred action in the action in the action'action:

```
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController?
    var totalTime = 600
    var time10 : UIAlertAction?
    var time20 : UIAlertAction?
    var timeCustom : UIAlertAction?
```

And during action initialisation :

```
    actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Set Timer", message: "--:--", preferredStyle: .alert)
    time10 = UIAlertAction(title: "10 Minutes", style: .default) {
        action in
        self.totalTime = 600
        self.startTimer()
        self.actionSheet?.preferredAction = self.time10
    }

    time20 = UIAlertAction(title: "20 Minutes", style: .default) {

        action in
        self.totalTime = 1200
        self.startTimer()
        self.actionSheet?.preferredAction = self.time20
    }

    let timeCustom = UIAlertAction(title: "Custom", style: .default) {
        action in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "customTimer", sender: nil)
        self.actionSheet?.preferredAction = self. and timertimeCustom
    }



@objc func updateTime() {
    
    print("update:- \(totalTime)")
    
    if totalTime != 0 {
        totalTime -= 1
    } else {        
        endTimer()
    }
    let hour = totalTime / 3600
    let minute = (totalTime - hour) / 60
    let seconds = (totalTime - hour) % 60
    actionSheet?.message = "\(hour):\(minute):\(seconds)"
}
```

First call :
[image]

Second call :
[image]

Comment: If I declare action as instance property(outside of the func) it works only for the first time. When I click the button app crash happens. The message is:- Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UIAlertController can only have one action with a style of UIAlertActionStyleCancel'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Updated for the highlight using prefferedAction

Comment: As I mention before your code is so far so good for the first time. But the problem is declaring the Alert Controller outside the function occurs an error. The error is when a user clicks the button to open the alert for second time the app crashes and show this: UIAlertController can only have one action with a style of UIAlertActionStyleCancel

Comment: I changed the code to use the prefferedAction property of the actionSheet. In this case actions can be .default and the preferedone is highlighted.

Comment: I fix it finally. Can you Update your code in the following way? Then I can accept your answer. let actionSheet: UIAlertController?   then actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Set Timer", message: "--:--", preferredStyle: .alert)

Comment: Updated the declaration of actionSheet

Answer (score 0):

Ptit Xav's answer is good, but it has a problem. When I open the alert for the second time app crashing.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UIAlertController can
> only have one action with a style of UIAlertActionStyleCancel'
> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Somehow I fix the problem, it is a minor fixing.

Define properties:-

```
let actionSheet : UIAlertController?
var totalTime = 600

var time10 : UIAlertAction?
var time20 : UIAlertAction?
var timeCustom : UIAlertAction?
```

Then inside the Action Function:-

```
func showActionSheetForSelectTimer() {
actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Set Timer", message: "--:--", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
 time10 = UIAlertAction(title: "10 Minutes", style: .default) {
        action in
        self.totalTime = 600
        self.startTimer()
        self.actionSheet?.preferredAction = self.time10
    }

    time20 = UIAlertAction(title: "20 Minutes", style: .default) {

        action in
        self.totalTime = 1200
        self.startTimer()
        self.actionSheet?.preferredAction = self.time20
    }

    let timeCustom = UIAlertAction(title: "Custom", style: .default) {
        action in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "customTimer", sender: nil)
        self.actionSheet?.preferredAction = self. and timertimeCustom
    }
        actionSheet?.addAction(cancel)
        actionSheet?.addAction(time10!)
        actionSheet?.addAction(time20!)
        actionSheet?.addAction(time30!)
        actionSheet?.addAction(time1!)
        actionSheet?.addAction(timeNever!)
        actionSheet?.addAction(timeCustom!)
        
        present(actionSheet!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
@objc func updateTime() {
    
    print("update:- \(totalTime)")
    
    if totalTime != 0 {
        totalTime -= 1
    } else {        
        endTimer()
    }
    let hour = totalTime / 3600
    let minute = (totalTime - hour) / 60
    let seconds = (totalTime - hour) % 60
    actionSheet.message = "\(hour):\(minute):\(seconds)"
}
```